# Main point of James Fenimore Cooper quote on history

Tags: phrase-meaning, quotes

“History, like love, is so apt to surround her heroes with an atmosphere of imaginary brightness.” James Fenimore Cooper

What is the main point the author is making here?

Comment: In other words historical figures weren't really as great as the history books claim they were.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't specify the source of confusion. Literary analysis is not on-topic for this site, and questions about the meaning of specific words should show research by citing sources like dictionary entries.

Answer (score 1):

It's like the expression "seeing (the past) through rose-tinted glasses." The positives surrounding the hero become exaggerated in our collective memory while the negatives are understated, or forgotten, or even purposely brushed under the rug.

Without knowing the context:

"History..." - Everyone and everything who participates in remembering things. You, your grandfather, or a book you read all contribute to how something is remembered.

"...like love..." - The simile works on two levels.  1) We love history. We are partial to it, and desire to make it better than it objectively is. 2) We are willing to pass a blind eye over the faults of people we love. In this case, our beloved is history, here personified as "her."

3) "...imaginary brightness" - The speaker is not saying that the brightness (wonder, goodness, romance) of the past is wholly imaginary. He's saying that we attribute more of it to history than it deserves– Or that you'd think it deserves, if you were experiencing it firsthand rather than through a recording.